# Jquery autocomplete with template

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a library that allows me to template the drop down list of an autocomplete box. I'll return data in json.

Comment: What do you mean template? as in specify like a sort of XSD for XML Schemas, but for JS?

Comment: I want to design the drop down list in html so the json can be assigned correctly.

Comment: something similar to using jTemplate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946949/jquery-autocomplete-jtemplates-handling-response

Comment: take a look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556561/asp-net-mvc-implementing-an-autocomplete-tags-selection-for-a-blog/4556778#4556778 and ignore the MVC part.  I do exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really suggest [Jquery UI - Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you don't like the output HTML of jQuery-autocomplete?

How about using jQuery [templates](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/)?

For example:

The template:

```
<script id="tmplDropDown" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<div>
    <select name="${ClassName}">
    {{each Options}}
        <option value="${Id}">${Name}</option>
    {{/each}}
    </select>
</div>
</script>
```

The JavaScript/ HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="sample">
<div id="results"></div>

<script>

$(function(){
   //bind on the textbox's keyup event.
   $('.sample').keyup(function(){  
       var value = $(this).val(); 

       //sample data, but normally do your server call here for json data with $.ajax
       var data = {
           "ClassName" : "example",
           "Options": [
               { "Id" :1, "Name" : "Stack"},
               { "Id" :2, "Name" : "Overflow"}
           ]
       };

       var $dropdown = $('#tmplDropDown').tmpl(data);
       $('#results').empty().append($dropdown);
});
</script>
```

And ofcoz, you can change the "select"/"option" to a "ul"/"li" or whatever the designer likes :)

Comment: I dont understand this, where is the `<input type="text" />`?

Comment: Edited, see if it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still relevant, just adding it for completeness: the original standalone jQuery autocompleter plugin that is still around (and actively developed):

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the code how I made it work
Use each function and it's good to use with multiple fields too.**

```
$('#query').each(function(i, el) {
    el = $(el);
    el.autocomplete({

        // get source using ajax function
        // If you need to send extra parameters to parts_by_partno.php
        // use data: {}
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'parts_by_partno.php',
                        
                // when you type word in text field
                // el.val() gets a word and ajax sends value of el.val() to server
                data: {id: el.attr('id'), term: el.val()},
              
                success: function(data) {
                    //data - data returned from server
                    response(data);
                },
                dataType:"json"
            })
        }
    });
});
```

**=================== in PHP ===================**

> $sendArray = array();
>
> ```
> $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE name LIKE '".$_GET['term']."%' LIMIT 10"
>
> while($row=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query)){
>
>   array_push($sendArray, $row['name']);
>
> };
>
> echo json_encode($sendArray);
> ```